# How do I delete a user's certificate while remoting to his laptop as admin?

Tags: powershell

While remoting in using a PS Session and as a Remote Admin, I need to delete a certificate from the store: CurrentUser\My.

I've noticed that while there are similar questions already, they do NOT answer my question. None of them address the problem of inserting local user as the context for the command.

I have tried recursing through the directories of ...\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA, changing the cert store to LocalMachine and inserting the username manually. Nothing works.

THIS WORKS

```
Get-ChildItem cert:"CurrentUser\My" | where {($_.Subject -like "*OU=CO*")} | remove-item -WhatIf
```

THIS DOES NOT (with remote session active)

```
 PS C:\Users\Remote Admin: Get-ChildItem cert:"CurrentUser\My" | where {($_.Subject -like "*OU=CO*")} | remove-item -WhatIf
```

Comment: CurrentUser means literally that, so unless the user who has the certificate on the remote computer is the same user you are remoting with you're looking at the wrong certificate store which explains why it doesn't work (LocalMachine is another store entirely, that applies to all users). One way around this could be to use a GPO to run this script when the user logs in, that way the "CurrentUser" context of the script should actually point to the right certificate store and be able to remove the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Certificates are stored in the [Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccrypto/system-store-locations) or in [LocalAppData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccrypto/certificate-store-migration).

If you have administrative rights you can access the registry remotely via [.Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openremotebasekey?view=netframework-4.8) for that user or the file system and remove the certificates as needed. Here's a test I ran.

First I created a dummy cert on a remote machine. This adds the cert to CurrentUser\My and CurrentUser\CA

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "www.fabrikam.com" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"
Thumbprint                                Subject                              
----------                                -------                     
E5A33C1BB6FBA8A6DA397C6BFE2CE489F751AF10  CN=www.fabrikam.com
```

Next I remotely access and remove the cert by thumbprint from Registry CA store.

```
$computer = 'ComputerA'
$targetSID = 'S-1-5-21-1234567890-1234567890-1234567890-12345' #get-aduser username
$reg = [Microsoft.win32.registryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('Users', $computer) #open remote registry
$avaliableSID = @($($reg.GetSubKeyNames() | Where-Object { $_ -match 'S-\d-\d+-(\d+-){1,14}\d+$' })) #get all users SIDS
if($avaliableSID -contains $targetSID ) #if it contains the one we want
{
    $otherUserStore = $reg.OpenSubKey("$targetSID\software\microsoft\systemcertificates\ca\certificates", $true) #open profile for writing
    $otherUserStore.DeleteSubKey('E5A33C1BB6FBA8A6DA397C6BFE2CE489F751AF10', $false) #delete key and suppress error if missing
}
```

I then remove it from the My store in %localappdata%

```
Remove-Item "\\$computer\c$\users\SOME.USER\appdata\roaming\microsoft\systemcertificates\my\certificates\$thumbprint" -Force #force required or you get access denied
```

Checking cert:\currentuser\my as that user shows no sign of the certificate. Of course you should add error checking, etc. but this example should help.